# jQuery UI slider in colorbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'd like to use a jQuery UI slider inside the colorbox plugin. In fact, any other slider will do, but it seems that none of them are working. It appears on the screen but there is no reaction when I'm trying to move it. This is probably a colorbox issue.

```
$('.cb').colorbox({
    html:'<div id="slider"></div><script>$('#slider').slider();</script>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your single quotes for slider or change them for double quotes. I personally would prefer the double quotes.

```
$('.cb').colorbox({
    html:'<div id="slider"></div><script>$("#slider").slider();</script>'
});
```